# Cannot write to Cassandra when adding a materialized view

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I am getting the following error when trying to write in Cassandra 3.

> Cassandra failure during write query at consistency ONE (1 responses
>   were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)

The error appears when trying to insert data to tables that have a materialized view.

Comment: It seems a column with user-defined data type in the source table is causing the problem. In other words, a table without user-defined column and materialized view is working correctly.

Comment: Check your Replication Factor on the keyspace

Comment: Replication Strategy: SimpleStrategy - Replication Factor: 1

Comment: You might have a node down

Comment: Hi phact, node seems up according to nodetool status